# dshow does not show as a valid input format for FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have just bought a DeckLink Quad HDMI recorder to do some screen capture and I want to use FFMPEG to do the recording.

I discovered that I had to compile FFMPEG with additional flags so I could use dshow as an input source. I followed these two guides for compiling:

https://gist.github.com/afriza/879fed4ede539a5a6501e0f046f71463
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Everything seemed to work fine, but when I run

```
  ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

it tells me "Unknown input format: 'dshow'"

When I run the command I can see the tags "--enable-nonfree  --enable-decklink"
I know the capture card is working because I can capture through OBS.

So I'm not sure why I can't use dshow

Here's the complete output of the terminal:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
ffmpeg version N-94264-g74d4fd0 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/capture/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-I/home/capture/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/capture/ffmpeg_sources/BMD_SDK/include' --extra-ldflags=-L/home/capture/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/capture/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-decklink
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 56.101 /  7. 56.101
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Unknown input format: 'dshow'
```

Comment: dshow is the **Windows** DirectShow input device. Try using the [decklink](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink) input device if you want to capture from the card. If you want to capture the screen an alternative is [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab).

Comment: Ah, my mistake. That works now. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[dshow](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) is the Windows DirectShow input device, so it won't be available on Linux.

Try using the [decklink](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink) input device if you want to capture from the Decklink card. If you want to capture the screen an alternative is [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab).